# Product details page not displayed

Tags: product

I have put my theme in fresh magento 1.9.2.2. And I added product at the backend. It is listed in frontend. The problem is that the details page is not displayed when I click the product link instead 404 error is diplayed. But when I open the Madison island products,the details page is available.Only the products which i add at the backend is not opening. Please help me to resolve this issue.

Comment: clear cache and re-index from index management, if not works then contact to your theme provider.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, you have to check your ".htaccess" file for "Rewrite Base" option, it should be either commented out or it should have the relative path if your site is inside subfolders.

Then you should clear cache and do re-indexing for all indexes. For that go to `System >> Cache Management >> Select All >> Submit` and also clear individual caches. For re-indexing go to `System >> Index Management >> Select All >> Submit`.

**Hope this helps you out**

Comment: It would be in your site root folder itself, turn on the hidden file display.

Comment: If this resolves your issue, then please accept it or if it was helpful then you can upvote it.

Comment: Try commenting it out, the `Rewrite Base` line. Then hard-refresh the page.

Comment: It is like this --> #RewriteBase /magento. What should be done

Comment: Then clear caches and do re-index as I mentioned in my answer.

Comment: Hey Issue got resolved when I cleared my cache.. thank you

Comment: I have tried and not working for me ...